# Laravel 9 How to hide listing the storage directory

Tags: laravel, apache

So My issue is as follows. My users can upload files and profile images into the app, Right clicking a profile image and opening in a new tab shows the image (which I want)

```
https:/my-app.com/storage/profile-photos/sad65f87as5f.png
```

If I remove the filename part of the url then I get forbidden which I also want

```
https:/my-app.com/storage/profile-photos
```

If I then however remove profile-photos from the url it lists all the folders in my storage directory. How do i make this forbidden?

```
https:/my-app.com/storage
```

In addition I have an uploads folder in the storage directory and this and all its contents are publicly available.

I'm using apache php8.1 and laravel9 in this project. It is also a production environment.

*** Solution ***

As alluded to in the comments below by DadoH, i needed to add code to stop indexing to the .htaccess file.

Adding to storage folder didn't work but adding the `Options -Indexes` line to the top of the .htaccess in the `public` folder did.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable browsing of a folder when there is no index, if you add `Options -Indexes` into your .htaccess in your storage folder.

Comment: Thankyou, had a feeling it would need to be a .htaccess solution